# Imagemapster de-select issue

Tags: jquery, imagemapster

I've read everything I can find, and maybe I'm overlooking something simple. I have a map of my campus, and everything highlights and selects properly. The only issue I'm having is this: when clicked, each building pops up an information bubble. There a 'X' close button on those bubbles. I'm trying to get the building to deselect when it's clicked. (I can't provide a live link unfortunately, currently staff/student access only).

Here's the map setup:

```
<img id="campus" style="top:420px; right:600px;" class=map src="localhost/display/images/map_off.jpg" usemap="#world" >

<map id="world" name="world" >                                                                                                                                

<area data-name="12" id="22" onclick="show_me(''12'')" shape="poly" coords="717,219,725" href="#/" alt="Building 1" />
<area data-name="22" id="22" onclick="show_me(''22'')" shape="poly" coords="693,459,699,459,693,472" href="#/" />
<area data-name="1" id="1" onclick="show_me(''1'')" shape="poly" coords="50,103,303,103,303,154,50,154,50,103" href="#/" alt="Building 2 /">
<area data-name="2" id="2" onclick="show_me(''2'')" shape="poly" coords="311,103,455,103,476,123,476,194,315,194" href="#/" alt="Building 3" />
```

And so on...

The setup:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      map = $("#campus");
      map.mapster({
              fillOpacity: 1,
              singleSelect: true,
              render_highlight: {
                 altImage: "localhost/display/images/map_on.jpg"
              },
              render_select: {
                 altImage: "localhost/display/images/map_on.jpg"
              }
      });    
});
```

and my close function:

the close function:

```
function closeWindow() {
          var selected_area = map.mapster(''get'');
          alert(selected_area); //this shows the correct map_key

          var select_status = map.mapster("get",map_key);
          alert(select_status); //but this shows 'false'

          $("#display_bubble").css("display","none");

        }
```

Any ideas? I get the feeling I'm overlooking something small, but I just can't find it.

Comment: You can replace those naughty `onclick=` attributes with a single jQuery call: `$('#world area').on('click', function(e) { show_me($(this).data('name')); })`

Comment: Can you share the `show_me` function? Or possibly build a working model on http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: The function doesn't have any code for Imagemapster, but I put show_me() here: http://jsfiddle.net/5bKUH/  - can't do a working model, it currently requires a campus login.

Comment: in the `closeWindow` function what is `map_key`? It's hard to figure out exactly what's going on without something to look at - actually i'm not even sure what is supposed to be happening. If you can't share the actual image to set up a working jsfiddle example for some reason, use `http://placekitten.com/width/height` as the source URL for in image instead e.g. http://placekitten.com/200/300

Comment: When the closeWindow function is called, im just trying to get the selected building to be deselected. I've tried various combinations of area.mapster(deselect) and area/img.mapster(set), but can't get it to fire correctly.  map_key is the key for the building that is selected

Comment: I'll see if I can get a working version w/o the db calls

Comment: By the way I think you had emailed me about this before (this is the author of imagemapster) and I don't remember if I dropped the ball.. but I'm glad you asked the question on SO, it's easier to deal with back & forth. I'll take a look at the fiddle if you can demonstrate the issue there.

Comment: Oh np, could be useful for others :) Do you have a public host for the js file I can link to?

Comment: https://raw.github.com/jamietre/ImageMapster/master/dist/jquery.imagemapster.js or http://www.outsharked.com/scripts/jquery.imagemapster.js is using IE (github doesn't send the right mime type & IE cares)

Comment: I updated the fiddle with a working version. the top left 3 buildings have the ids and keys set. but bubble doesn't move, but that's not important. The goal is to deselect the building when the X in the bubble is clicked

Comment: I got it working. for some reason the map_key isn't holding the value. So, call the selected key with selected_area = map.mapster(''get'') and use that to map.mapster("set",false,selected_area)

Comment: I'm wrong. It fixes the close function, but now clicking the building again doesn't deselect it, but closes the bubble. I'll look into that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case this happens with anyone else, I had the 'mapKey' set under options:, instead of :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  map = $("#campus");
  map.mapster({
          fillOpacity: 1,
          ...
  });
 options:({   
   mapKey: "data-name",
   ...
```

});

it needed to be :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  map = $("#campus");
  map.mapster({
          mapKey: "data-name",
          fillOpacity: 1,
          ...
  }); 
  options:({
          ...
```

});